# How to convince Eclipse to offer non-requisite methods?

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

(Eclipse v4.2.2/JDT v3.8.2)

How can I convince Eclipse to offer eg, Serializable's readObject(...) and writeObject(...) when using content assist? These methods never appear in the list of method names, even when the surrounding class implements Serializable.

Additionally, if this is possible, how would I customize the skeleton to contain eg, *in.defaultReadObject();*?

I understand why they don't appear, but is there any way to make them do so?

Comment: `Serializable` does not contain any methods. Can you add more details about what exactly you want Eclipse to do?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I should've been clearer. The methods readObject and writeObject that are associated with a custom implementation of Serializable. I would like Eclipse to offer to auto-complete these method names (with skeleton) when I open content-assist with Ctrl-Space...

Comment: So what do you want Eclipse to do exactly? Can you describe a scenario?

Comment: 1) I create a class that either implements Serializable, or has a super class that implements Serializable. 2) I open content-assist with ctrl-space. 3) I press either 'r' or 'w', and Eclipse offers, amongst other methods, 'readObject' or 'writeObject'... I'm sorry, I don't know how else to express this. I thought content-assist was a pretty popular feature of Eclipse.

Comment: Yes it is. I primarily use it to avoid typing out method names when I am calling them. However, it sounds like you are trying to use it to help in implementing the methods. Is that right?

Comment: No. It's to save me typing out 'private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException { in.defaultReadObject(); }' every time.

Comment: That thing Eclipse does with every other method in content-assist? I want that exact same thing to happen with readObject and writeObject.

Comment: So yes, you are implementing the methods, not trying to call them. AFAICT, Eclipse can only do this when you attempt to **override** a method from a parent class or interface. Since you are not overriding methods here, I don't think Eclipse will do this. My best suggestion is to look for a plugin that will do what you want.

Comment: OK, thanks. I think a plugin is overkill, so I guess I'd best practise my typing.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a [Code Template](http://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2006/02/27/code-template-expansion-in-eclipse/). These are helpful for all kinds of repetitive code tasks. You'll never have to type a for loop again.